# SP13: Copy List Items into Same Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, calculated-column

I have a custom list using SharePoint 2013. In the list, there are a few single line text columns. Let's say Column #1 (single text) and Column #2 (single text).  What I am trying to do is since SharePoint columns are listed horizontally I am trying to take the text inside column #1 and column #2 and copy into a new list and new column underneath each other (as their own line item).

Can I create a workflow that copies column #1 and column #2 and updates it into a new list in the same column different rows?  If this would work I know how to copy and update but can't update into same column different row.  Can anyone help me? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is manually possible (`there is no dynamic solution`) depending on how many columns in `List1` that you need to convert them to rows in `List2`.

To achieve that you can add `Create List Item` Action in `List2` based on the number of columns in `List1` as the following:

- Add `Create List Item` Action

[image]

- Select your `List2` in Create List Item Dialog

[image]

- Now click add to add the column 1 of `list2`

[image]

- As above shown, specify the value for the column 1 of `List1`
- Repeat the above action by copying it.

[image]

- Just click on the copied action to open it > Select column1 > click modify > replact its **value** with the column2 in `List1`

**Note:** this workflow should be started on item added not changed, in case you need to enable on item changed you should add another column in list2 as id that will hold the row id of list 1 to be working as a reference when the item in list1 changed

Comment: This is good.  Thank you. If it has another column of information connected to column 2 do I create a Create List Item for those columns too?

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't catch your question? what do you mean with  has another column of information connected to column 2?

Comment: It's another metadata column.  For example column #3 has information about column#2 in it.  Do I create a List Item for that column too so it appears next to column#2 after it has been moved underneath column #1?  Maybe lookup column can work in this situation.

Comment: Yes, it will work, and as I mentioned in my answer: it is manually possible (there is no dynamic solution) depending on how many columns in List1 that you need to convert them to rows in List2. so if you have 5 column you need to create 5 create item action so it's not dynamic to detect automatically the number of columns,  unfortunately, there is no way to achieve this dynamic without code else what I have mentioned! Hope you got it ! also please if this answer helped you kindly don't forget to mark it as an answer and upvote it, Thanks!